# Run mode not there (IDLE Python 3.6)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, python-idle, python-3.6

Probably a very simple question. I just thought, after someone suggested it here, of trying (and installing) Python 3.6 on a Mac - I've been happily using 2.7 since now. I've never used the IDLE before having done everything via the command line + ATOM to write the program.

I see that 'normally' you should be able to write your program in the shell and then run it in the RUN window. However, I don't see a RUN mode in window, just the possibility of using, which you are anyhow, the shell window. I hope that makes sense!

Is this normal, or have I missed something?

p.s. I'm using OS X 10.8, if that's of any importance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, and whether it has anything to do with OSX, but I can explain IDLE.  IDLE has two types of main window: a single Shell and multiple Editor windows.

Shell simulates python running in the interactive REPL mode that you get when you enter 'python' (or 'python3') in a console or terminal window.  (The latter depends on the OS.)  You enter statements at the `>>>` prompt.  A single-line statement is run when you hit `Enter` (or `Return`).  A multi-line statement is run when you hit `Enter` twice.  This is the same as in interactive Python.

Editor windows let you enter a multi-statement program.  You run the programs by selecting `Run` and `Run module` from the menu or by hitting the shortcut key, which by default is `F5` (at least on Windows and Linux).  This runs the program much the same as if you enter `python -i myprogram.py` in a console.  Program output and input goes to and is received from the Shell window.  When the program ends, Python enters interactive mode and prints an interactive prompt (`>>>`).  One can then interact with the objects created by the program.

You are correct that `Run` does not appear on the menu bar of the Shell.  It is not needed as one runs a statement with the `Enter` key.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly - when learning python - the best thing to do is to simply write your program in a separate editor (ex: Atom), and then run it in the terminal window? I must say that I don't quite understand your multi-line statement as I'm still learning. If I tap enter twice I still get (>>>) which just waits for the next command, and not the second part of a command, but maybe that's a second question. Thanks for your clear explanation.

Comment: No, I suggest learning python by using IDLE unless and until one decides to learn a more advanced IDE.  I should have said 'compound' rather than 'multiline'.  A multiline statement is either a simple statement continued over more than one physical line (`a = (1 + 2 + 3\n    +4 + 4)` or a compound statement with a header on one line and a body on one or more following lines (`if a:\n    b = 3`).  Tapping Enter twice is only needed for a compound statement.  Other compound statements are `def`, `class`, `while`, and `for`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get my head down and start working - "Python for Absolute Beginners".